# jQuery animation stopped working after upgrading from 1.7.1 to 2.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using the following code with jQuery 1.7.1, but, after upgrading to jQuery 2.1.1 it stopped working. Can you help me understand what's wrong?

```
$(function() {        
        $('#block').hover(function(){            
        $('#block').stop(true, false).animate({left: '0' }, 800, 'easeOutQuint' );        
        },
  function(){            
        $('#block').stop(true, false).animate({left: '-241px' }, 800, 'easeInQuint' );        
        },1000);    
});
```

Comment: How does this not work? On which browser? Keep in mind jQuery 2.x does not support IE8 and lower.

Comment: well in this case you might want to look at jQuery migrate plugin.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have check in Latest firefox & chrome. Thanks.

Comment: In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8tk2wko/) the function itself is working, but the easing seems to be missing. With a linear-easing it all works fine

Comment: @empiric ... easing need jQuery UI. ;) Add jQuery UI and all works.
I update your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8tk2wko/1/

Comment: @Frogmouth I was forgot to jquery.easing.min.js file. Thanks.